# Python 2.6 64 bit - scipy.ndimage import error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, importerror, ndimage

Using the 64 bit version of python 2.6, I installed the unofficial 64 bit scipy module from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy. I tried running a script that specifically uses the scipy.ndimage module, which leads to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PhantomAnalysis.py", line 79, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\__init__.py", line 175, in <
module>
    from .measurements import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\measurements.py", line 36, i
n <module>
    from . import _ni_label
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I'm just not able to import scipy.ndimage at all using those packages. Is this an issue with the package or with my installation/configuration?

I can provide any other relevant information.

Comment: Where is your python binary from? Chris Gohlke's Windows installers assume you're using the "official" python binary from python.org. If it's not the one provided by python.org, you'll likely have problems. (e.g. Let's say you're trying to install scipy for the python distributed with ArcGIS)

Comment: @JoeKington I am using the official binary:

<https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6/python-2.6.amd64.msi>

Comment: No idea, then.  There's a note on Chris Gohlke's installer page that many of the installers don't work properly on XP, in case you happen to be using it.  Other than that, though, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Use [Python 2.6.6](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/), which contains many bug fixes.